# Is there an official Docker Engine security notices mailing list or other channel?

Tags: docker

Is there an official Docker security mailing list (or other channel) which I can subscribe to for notices on vulnerabilities/fixes to the Docker Engine? Similar to the official Ubuntu notices at http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a security-specific mailing list that I know of, but you can subscribe to Google Groups - [Docker-Dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/docker-dev) or [Docker User](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/docker-user) get security updates.

There's also [Docker's CVE database](https://www.docker.com/docker-cve-database) and the Center for Internet Security publish a benchmark for each Docker Engine release - [this is the current one, for Docker 1.12](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/show-single/?file=docker12.100).

Comment: Looks like you can now subscribe to the Announcements category on forums.docker.com. The Docker User Google Group was moved.

Comment: Most of these links are broken now.

Answer (score 1):

Although not limited to security updates, you can subscribe to Github releases (including via RSS): https://github.com/moby/moby/releases